# Firebase: Enable the Google Cloud Build API for your Cloud Functions project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hi I am using firebase and the firebase functions.

1 day ago I received an email from Google Cloud with the following content:

> Starting April 20, 2020, Cloud Functions will use Google Cloud Build, Container Registry, and Google Cloud Storage to build and store your source code, and deploy container image(s) before running them on Google Cloud. You must enable the Cloud Build API for your project(s) to ensure your Cloud Function is built and deployed correctly. Once you enable the API, you may incur charges if your Cloud Build, Container Registry, or Cloud Storage usage exceeds the free tier limits for these products. You can find a list of your projects that are using Cloud Functions and may be affected by this change at the bottom of this email.

I tend to avoid tinkering the Google Cloud (or even logging in there) as I am using the Firebase as an all inclusive solution and so far I did not have the need to login there.

Now the question:

Do I need to follow the instructions and take action, or is this something separate from the Firebase Functions?

The "affected" project that is mentioned on the email is the Firebase project

Comment: You should reach out to Firebase support directly to get a statement about this.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use cloud functions after April 20, 2020 you must enable the Cloud Build API because this will be a new deployment framework.
You will not be able to use cloud functions if you do not enable the Cloud Build API after this date.
These changes will apply even for Firebase cloud functions.

Comment: was that part of the email ? Just checking :-D

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need to do it only if you are going to deploy Cloud Functions in the future, Cloud Functions already deployed will not be affected.

In case you are worried about billing, Cloud Build provides a free tier where only usage above 120 build-minutes/day will be charged. When your usage is within the free tier, you will not be charged for the Cloud Build portion of Cloud Function deployments. See [Cloud Build pricing](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/pricing) for more information.

Similarly, Cloud Storage and Container Registry share a free tier where only usage above 5GB-months will be charged. ( * Note : free tier only limited to US regions - US-WEST1, US-CENTRAL1, and US-EAST1 and aggregated over all 3 regions )​ For example, if you have a large deployment that uses 100GB of storage, you will only be charged an additional $2.47 for storage/month (based on these particular U.S. regional storage prices).

You can monitor your usage and see whether you are getting close to hitting the free quotas.

This is a best effort from Google to communicate information that is necessary to the user’s continued use of the product or that is considered a necessary legal update and keep customers away from having future issues

Using Cloud Build, Container Registry and Cloud Storage provides the following benefits:

- Detailed function build logs will be available in the GCP Console, aiding in debugging and increasing visibility.
- The ability to get build time that exceeds the current build quota of 120 build-mins/day.
- The ability to view a built container image for your function in Container Registry.

Comment: Cloud functions already deployed will be affected I'm afraid. They are specifically listed in the email.